# Invoke Kotlin compiler from Java program

Tags: kotlin

Is there kind of thing allow me to compile Kotlin program in memory, like ECJ (the Eclipse java compiler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I believe [K2JVMCompiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/cli/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/jvm/K2JVMCompiler.kt) will satisfy your needs.

I don't believe you will find much documentation for it though. The best place to start would probably be in Kotlin's own smoke tests which use the class.

Comment: You can find a sample of using the Kotlin compiler within the Kobalt build system.  See this file here: https://github.com/cbeust/kobalt/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/beust/kobalt/plugin/kotlin/KotlinCompiler.kt

Comment: Also, note that `K2MVCompiler` does **not** support incremental compilation just yet, this is only supported in IDEA (and soon Gradle I hear).

Comment: @CedricBeust thanks; I've edited my answer accordingly